# Uncaught channelUrl must be under the current domain

Tags: support, api-v2.2, javascript, documentation

I'm developing a Stack Chrome extension that will make use of the API. I'm following the instructions on the API docs [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib).

My OAuth and host websites are set to `stackexchange.com` in my Stack Apps settings.

I am using `SE.init()` to initialise an API call.

My `channelURL` is set to `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/proxy` as instructed, but when I try and call `init` it throws:

> Uncaught channelUrl must be under the current domain

I've read through many other threads about using localhost etc but I'm not using any of that. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: From the docs: *channelUrl – a blank page under the same domain as the including page.*. I don't think you own the domain stackexchange.com and due that  fact your channelUrl should not point to https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/proxy but to an endpoint/page on your server.

Comment: I see, I think I understand now however I do not actually have a server on my end. Instead, I think I'll use localhost and React. I will update how it goes.